# how can i loop to read, load and parse files in python

Tags: python, json

I need to take user input for no.of files, suppose user enters 'n' then a loop should run to read , load the files. For eg - incase of 4 files, we do this where file name is saved as- name(prime number) ...but i want to use loop incase the no.of file increases

```
with open ('name0.json', 'r') as f1:
    data1= json.load(f1)
with open ('name2.json', 'r') as f2:
    data2= json.load(f2)
with open ('name4.json', 'r') as f3:
    data3= json.load(f3)
with open ('name6.json', 'r') as f4:
    data4= json.load(f4)
```

Comment: by "prime number" you mean "even" numbers aka numbers that are devisable by two. Bc prime numbers are something completely different than what you have shown in your example

Comment: sorry my bad...i meant even numbers not prime numbers

Answer (score 0):

This code reads the given amount of files into a list for further processing . It only read all files with a even number.

```
import json

user_input = None

while type(user_input) != type(int):
    user_input = input("Please enter a number of files to read: ")

files = []

for index in range(0, int(user_input)+1, 2):
    with open(f"file{index}.json", "r") as file:
        files.append(json.load(file))
```